# 2 column layout until first column height is done and then one column layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, sveltekit

My webpage has a 2 column layout, left side is filters and right side is articles, like this:
[image: 2 column layout]

Goals:

- Fixed width filters (left side) @ big viewport
- Full width filters above articles (one column layout) @ small viewport
- @ big viewport stack articles on right till we get to the height end of 1st column and then full width articles, like this:

[image: End of 2 column layout]

I am currently doing this with JS `getBoundingClientRect()` but would love to know if there is a CSS solution please?!

As requested, current JS solution via `SvelteKit`:

```js
import {
  onMount
} from 'svelte';
import type {
  PageData
} from './$types'
import Source from '$lib/components/Source.svelte'
import type {
  QuoteCategory
} from '$lib/util/types'
import AuthorChips from '$lib/components/chips/AuthorChips.svelte'
import QuoteCategoryChips from '$lib/components/chips/QuoteCategoryChips.svelte'

export let data: PageData
let categories: QuoteCategory[]
if (data.categories) categories = data.categories

onMount(fullSizeSources)

function fullSizeSources() {
  let wideDone = false
  const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop
  const authors = document.getElementById('author-chips')
  const sources = document.getElementsByClassName('source')
  const authorBottom = (authors ? .getBoundingClientRect() ? .bottom || 0) + scrollTop

  for (let source of sources) {
    if (wideDone || (source.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollTop) > authorBottom) {
      wideDone = true
      source.classList.add('full')
    } else {
      source.classList.remove('full')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .left {
    max-width: 36rem;
    margin-right: 1.8rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
   :global(.source.full) {
    margin-left: -37rem;
    width: calc(100% + 37rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    { #if data.categories }
    <QuoteCategoryChips categories={ data.categories } location="nav" /> { /if } { #if data.authors }
    <AuthorChips authors={ data.authors } /> { /if }
  </div>

  <div>
    { #if data.sources } { #each data.sources as source }
    <Source { source } /> { /each } { /if }
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide HTML and any CSS to reproduce this right here IN the question (and the JavaScript you have tried perhaps since you mention that)

Comment: I made a snippet of the code - does not really run as it is since it is missing the library parts. FWIW Since this is really about the HTML and CSS it may perhaps serve to post the rendered HTML and CSS here (perhaps as an additional snippet?)

Comment: Pretty sure there is currently no CSS solution for this, but I'd be happy to be wrong.

Comment: @MoritzRingler It is possible! See accepted answer! Yay!

Comment: Very nice! Didn't know that flow and flex interact that way. Thank you for pinging @gmustudent !

Comment: Actually it is worth noting that `float: left` will indeed be ignored if you use `display: flex` for the parent container. But for children no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can solve this problem by using float and @media. For small viewport use normal layout with one column. For big viewport you can use `float: left;` so that your articles are on the right side and after reaching the height of the left column they become 100% width.

```css
/* Just some styles to visualise. Notice the use of flex, it makes it easier to work with the content of these elements */

.left,
.right-article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}


/* Replace 600px with whatever you need */

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .left {
    /* Replace the width with whatever you need */
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Exercitationem et qui fuga non illo nemo, harum ab, vero in illum maxime, dolore dignissimos velit provident id iure accusantium fugiat amet!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>

  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit..</div>

  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>

  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit..</div>

  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>

  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit..</div>

  <div class="right-article">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```